# Появление и исчезание <div> через заданное время

Tags: javascript, html

Как можно сделать появление `div class="loader"` по нажатию на кнопку `button` , и исчезанию его по истечении 40 секунд? Как это возможно реализовать с помощью JavaScript? Есть ли варианты с прикреплением таймера? Заранее спасибо.

```css
body{
  padding: 1em;
  background: #2B3134;
  color: #777;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Gill sans", sans-serif;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h1{
  margin: 1em 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.loader{
  margin: 0 0 2em;
  height: 100px;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

/*
  Set the color of the icon
*/
svg path,
svg rect{
  fill: #FF6700;
}
.w3-button {width:160px;}
```

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <p><button class="w3-button w3-red">START</button></p>
  <div class="loader loader--style3" title="2">
  <svg  version="1.1" id="loader-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="80px" height="80px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve">
  <path fill="#000" d="M43.935,25.145c0-10.318-8.364-18.683-18.683-18.683c-10.318,0-18.683,8.365-18.683,18.683h4.068c0-8.071,6.543-14.615,14.615-14.615c8.072,0,14.615,6.543,14.615,14.615H43.935z">
    <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
      attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 25 25"
      to="360 25 25"
      dur="0.6s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </path>
  </svg>
  
</div>
 <p style="text-indent: 0.0em;color:white;">  You have 40 seconds for prepare your interview.</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `setTimeout()`:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn'),
  loader = document.getElementsByClassName('loader')[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  loader.style.display = 'block'; // показываем .loader
  setTimeout(function() {
    loader.style.display = 'none'; // скрываем .loader
  }, 2000); // зарежка перед скрытием в миллисекундах
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
  background: #2B3134;
  color: #777;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Gill sans", sans-serif;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  margin: 1em 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.loader {
  margin: 0 0 2em;
  height: 100px;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: none;
}


/*
  Set the color of the icon
*/

svg path,
svg rect {
  fill: #FF6700;
}

.w3-button {
  width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<p><button class="w3-button w3-red" id="btn">START</button></p>
<div class="loader loader--style3" title="2">
  <svg version="1.1" id="loader-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="80px" height="80px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve">
  <path fill="#000" d="M43.935,25.145c0-10.318-8.364-18.683-18.683-18.683c-10.318,0-18.683,8.365-18.683,18.683h4.068c0-8.071,6.543-14.615,14.615-14.615c8.072,0,14.615,6.543,14.615,14.615H43.935z">
    <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
      attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 25 25"
      to="360 25 25"
      dur="0.6s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </path>
  </svg>

</div>
<p style="text-indent: 0.0em;color:white;"> You have 40 seconds for prepare your interview.</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а возможно ли сделать не с применением id="btn", а с использованием class?

Comment: @OlegSevernuy можно. по тому же принципе, что и .loader определяется